# With the Arduino Ethernet shield, what's the difference between `write()`, `print()`, and `printIn()`?

Tags: arduino, ethernet

Using the [Arduino Ethernet Server Library](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/Ethernet), **what is the difference between:**

`server.write(data);`,
`server.print(data);`, and
`server.println(data);`

I know that the `printIn` adds a new line, where `print` does not. I cannot find any examples for `server.write();`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Long answer, skip to **TL;DR** at the bottom if unwieldy)

#### Where `print()` and `write()` come from

To find out, we can look at the source.  `Server` is an instance of the `EthernetServer` class defined in `arduino/libraries/Ethernet/EthernetServer.h` (selected lines only)

```
#include "Server.h"

class EthernetClient;

class EthernetServer : 
public Server {
private:
public:
  virtual size_t write(uint8_t);
  virtual size_t write(const uint8_t *buf, size_t size);
  using Print::write;
};
```

Ok, so it is a `Server`. `Server` is defined in `/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/Server.h`, and there is very little to it:

```
class Server : public Print {
public:
  virtual void begin() =0;
};
```

This means that server is a subclass of `Print` so we can look for differences between `write()` and `print()` there.

#### `print()` and `write()` parameters

We see that this class (i.e. `Print`) defines a number of overloaded `print()` methods:

```
size_t print(const __FlashStringHelper *);
size_t print(const String &);
size_t print(const char[]);
size_t print(char);
size_t print(unsigned char, int = DEC);
size_t print(int, int = DEC);
size_t print(unsigned int, int = DEC);
size_t print(long, int = DEC);
size_t print(unsigned long, int = DEC);
size_t print(double, int = 2);
size_t print(const Printable&);
```

and three overloaded `write()` methods:

```
virtual size_t write(uint8_t) = 0;
size_t write(const char *str) { return write((const uint8_t *)str, strlen(str)); }
virtual size_t write(const uint8_t *buffer, size_t size);
```

As you can see the C-string `write` uses the block `write` (the third method), and in the default implementation, the block write uses a byte write (the first method), which is pure virtual method: `virtual size_t write(uint8_t) = 0;`. It must be overriden in every class that derives from `Print`. Additionally the block `write()` may be overriden as well in order to write multi-byte data more efficiently.

So, parameter-wise:

- `write()`: on bytes (`uint8_t`), byte buffers, and char array pointers (= regular C strings)
- `print()`: Arduino `String`s, `int`s and `long`s (in whatever base), `float`s, and any class derived from `Printable`, in addition to `chars` and C strings.

As you can see, formally, there is little overlap between the parameters `write()` and `print()` takes. For instance only `write()` takes `uint8_t`, but only `print()` can take a `char`. The only area of overlap is the C-style strings: there is `print(const char[]);` and `write(const char *str);`. However, even in cases like `char` the `print()` function simply calls the `write(uint8_t)`:

```
size_t Print::print(char c)
{
  return write(c);
}
```

The same is true for `print(char[])`

#### `write()` in `EthernetServer

The `EthernetServer` class introduces a block write method

```
size_t EthernetServer::write(const uint8_t *buffer, size_t size)
```

and in the `EthernetServer` the `write(uint8_t)` simply thunks to the block write:

```
size_t EthernetServer::write(uint8_t b) 
{
  return write(&b, 1);
}
```

Since all the `print()` calls and non-`uint8_t` `write()` calls use either `write(uint8_t)` or `write(uint8_t*, size_t)`, in the `EthernetServer` class every `print`/`write` call is made using the block write.

#### Performance and choosing between `print()` and `write()`

The thunking `print()` functions (such as `print(char c)`) will be most-likely be inlined by the gcc compiler, though if you are worried about this you can call `write()` instead of `print()`.

One case where you *might* want to call `write()` instead of `print()` to save a couple of clock cycles is where you are holding a `byte`/`uint8_t` and you need to print that. Using `print()` your data will need to be converted to a 4-byte value (`int`) and then printed using more code. In this case `write()` will be a tiny bit faster.

On the other hand, code consistency is probably worth something too. From this perspective it might make sense to make all `print()` calls.

Most of the time, however, your types will dictate calling the `print()` function: write can only take three types of input.

---

**TL;DR**: The answer to your question then is that there isn't much difference between `print()` and `write()` except:

- The `write()` methods (byte or block) are the methods that do the actual work of sending characters somewhere, in every case.
- `write()` can take bytes (`uint8_t`), byte buffers, and char array pointers (= regular C strings) as parameters, whereas `print()` takes Arduino `String`s, `int`s and `long`s (in whatever base), `float`s, and any class derived from `Printable`, in addition to `chars` and C strings. So we might say that `write()` is lower level than `print()`, given the fact that it only takes low-level types.
- Most of the time your output types will dictate which one to use. To make the fastest code use `write()` for printing `byte`/`uint8_t` types, but `print` everywhere makes your code look a teensy bit better IMHO (mainly because it doesn't raise the `print()` versus `write()` questions).

Comment: So why would anybody use `write()`? Is it faster if you are already using the variable type it supports?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out: that was a flaw in the answer. I tried to address it, but that made the answer even longer :(  Let me know if that doesn't clear it up.